# iOS 6 + phonegap -- Splash screen rotates without interaction

Tags: ios, cordova

So, I had a phonegap app that worked fine on iOS 5, but when iOS 6 debuted the only issue introduced into the application is that now on the iPad, only, when I run my application in Landscape orientation, the splash screen will now load up and show correctly, then the app flashes and the splash screen rotates 90 degrees clockwise, and apparently moves 20-30 px, roughly, to the left.

It appears that it's trying to use a Portrait oriented splash screen, instead of the landscape one, but all the files are the correct ones, so I've run out of ideas on where to look.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, as this last little thing is the only thing preventing me pushing my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [here](http://xdumaine.com/2012/09/21/phonegap-in-ios-6/)

or update to **phonegap 2.1**

Comment: I did this fix, but I'm still seeing the splash screen flip 90 degrees on startup (runs portrait even though app is in landscape)

Comment: I upgraded to phonegap 2.1, and still have this issue. Here's a little more detailed code view that may help with finding a solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606978/splash-screen-issue-xcode-ios-6-phonegap