# Splash Screen issue, Xcode/iOS 6/Phonegap

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

So, I have this function in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{        
    [CDVLocalStorage __verifyAndFixDatabaseLocations];
    NSURL* url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (url && [url isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
        invokeString = [url absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"PHR launchOptions = %@", url);
    }
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.detailViewController
    self.detailViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    self.detailViewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
    self.detailViewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    self.detailViewController.startPage = @"index.html";
    self.detailViewController.invokeString = invokeString;
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    if (![deviceType hasPrefix:@"iPad"] && ![deviceType hasPrefix:@"iPad Simulator"])
    {   
        CGRect viewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        detailViewController.view.frame = viewBounds;

        BOOL forceStartupRotation = YES;
        UIDeviceOrientation curDevOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

        if (UIDeviceOrientationUnknown == curDevOrientation) {
            curDevOrientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        }

        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(curDevOrientation)) {
                if ([self.detailViewController supportsOrientation:curDevOrientation]) {
                    forceStartupRotation = NO;
                }
        } 

        if (forceStartupRotation) {
            UIInterfaceOrientation newOrient;
            if ([self.detailViewController supportsOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
                newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            else if ([self.detailViewController supportsOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
                newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            else if ([self.detailViewController supportsOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight])
                newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
             else
                newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;

            NSLog(@"AppDelegate forcing status bar to: %d from: %d", newOrient, curDevOrientation);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:newOrient];
        }

        self.window.rootViewController = self.detailViewController;
    } else {
        NavViewController *leftViewController = [[NavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *leftNavViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftViewController];
        leftNavViewController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
        detailNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        leftViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

        self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftNavViewController, detailNavigationController, nil];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
        self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
        detailViewController.svc = self.splitViewController;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Yes, I know it's a lot of code, but I'm completely unsure of what to snip because inside of this function I don't know what's exactly wrong.

Essentially, my app loads on the ipad in landscape mode, but the splash screen rotates 90 degrees and shows portrait instead of landscape, then flashes back to my actual splash screen. From looking at the code, I can tell that it's firing in the else statement of the device check, other than that I could really use your guys' help in figuring out what changes I need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I FINALLY managed to get this solved. In CDVViewController.m in the Cordova files (you have to have 2.0.0 to even get the sources) in the "showSplashScreen" function you have to comment out the line `startupImageTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));` in all of the if checks, because the device does the rotation for you, then phonegap tries to re-orient it.

Answer (score 1):

Set `setStatusBarOrientation` to landscape modes only, if you are only working with landscape mode in your application.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

Comment: I need all 4 interfaces available on the iPad only, and portrait only for the iPod and iPhone. The orientations work fine, they boot up and are interactable in all orientations, just the splash screen rotates wrong and is the only thing holding my iOS 6 compatible update.

Comment: please add this line `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:curDevOrientation];` after `forceStartupRotation = NO;`

Comment: No luck. I added it in non-Ipad part as well as the iPad part, and it still rotates the splash screen once xcode connects. It shows the right splash, xcode connects and it shows a rotated (portrait) splash, then it goes to my loading screen.

Comment: a last try, please hide the status bar, like `[application statusBarHidden:TRUE];
`

Comment: Still flips for no apparent reason. Ughh! This is really pissing me off.

Comment: I was suffering with same issue, I fixed the issue by setting the status bar orientation to landscape right. My app only works in landscape mode, that's why I didn't see the issue in portrait mode.